# Exact meaning of "$\pi/2$ pulse"

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, quantum-optics, bloch-sphere

In studying Mach-Zehnder and Ramsey interferometers, I came across the expression "$\pi/2$ pulse". What does it mean exactly? I am working with a Bloch vector representation $(u,v,w)$ of a 2 state system. We have a Rabi frequency $\Omega_0$ and a detuning parameter $\delta$ to the $|1\rangle\rightarrow|2\rangle$ transition frequency. In those conditions, I think the "$\pi/2$ pulse" is a rotation around the $(-\Omega_0,0,-\delta)$ axis for a duration $\tau=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{\Omega_0^2+\delta^2}}$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$

Lets say we want to change the state of a spin initially at $\ket{+}$ $\rightarrow$ $\ket{-}$ in a Bloch Sphere. In other words we want to rotate the spin by $\pi$ radians about $z$ axis or $y$ axis in a Bloch Sphere. Lets select $z$ axis, such that

$$ R_{z}(\pi)\ket{+} = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{2} \sigma_{z}}\ket{+}$$
$$ R_{z}(\pi)\ket{+} = [\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})I -i \sin(\frac{\pi}{2})\sigma_{z}]    \ket{+}$$
which upto a global phase can be written as,
$$ R_{z}(\pi)\ket{+} = \sigma_{z}\ket{+}$$
$$ R_{z}(\pi)\ket{+} = \ket{-}$$

Thus, $R_{z}(\pi)$ or $\pi$ pulse effectively rotates the system by $\pi$ radians. Similarly $\frac{\pi}{2}$ pulse rotates a system by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians in a Bloch sphere, which for above example is given by
$$ R_{z}(\frac{\pi}{2})\ket{+} = e^{-i \frac{\pi}{4} \sigma_{z}}\ket{+}$$
$$ R_{z}(\frac{\pi}{2})\ket{+} = [\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})I -i \sin(\frac{\pi}{4})\sigma_{z}]    \ket{+}$$
$$ R_{z}(\frac{\pi}{2})\ket{+} = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ket{+} -i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ket{-}]$$
$$ R_{z}(\frac{\pi}{2})\ket{+} = [\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ket{0} +i \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ket{1}] = \ket{+}_{y}$$

Answer (score -6):

$\frac{π}{2}$ pulse means that all the particles in the system have gone to the higher level. $π$ pulse excites all particles in the first half time and de-exites in the second, so all particles are in lower level.

Comment: We use mathjax here.

Comment: Despite being the accepted answer, this is not correct. A $\pi$ pulse sends $|0\rangle\to|1\rangle$. A $\pi/2$ pulse sends $|0\rangle\to(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. The most intuitive reason for this naming is how the corresponding Bloch sphere vectors transform (spoilers: rotation by $\pi$ and $\pi/2$, respectively.) Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabi_problem

Comment: Does a pi/2 pulse also send 1 to something, or is 1 left unchanged??

Comment: @Daniel No longer the accepted answer. I have no idea how I could have accepted this as the answer!